# Reload web page in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt

After a user logged and press my page url  in this page  if user press confirm button  i want to relaod my page not the home page

```
 Window.alert(ConstantesMessage.MESSAGE_MSG004);
                                eventBus.goToMyPage();
                                Window.Location.reload();
```

this solution work but it's reload the home page not my page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GWT application is a single page application. So if you reload the web page you get your start page, unless you use the history tokens. See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html When you have a history token the page is still reloaded, but based on the history token you can open the page you want to show. I guess you don't have the history token set, so you'll get your home page.

As an extra thought. It looks like you built the login in GWT. A better solution is to provide a separate login page. And when the user is successfully logged in then open the application.